# How to tim() a string value from a template in a cshtml page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, razor

I have this portion of code:

```
@Html.MyTextBoxFor(m => m.list[i].value, new { Label = "", DivClass = "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12", TextArea = true, NamePrefix = prefix })
```

```
public static IHtmlString MyTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> ex, object additionalViewData)
    {
        return html.EditorFor(ex, "_TextField", additionalViewData);
    }
```

I tried to trim the model but as soon as I open the page in question I find a string "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t my value\n\t\t"

I expected that by doing the tim() in the modem and in the controller before saving, I would see the string without tabs or new lines on the screen, however without spaces

Comment: Have you tried `.Replace()` ? You would replace both `\n` and `\t` by `string.Empty` to have a neat string as an output

Comment: Yes I try to replace \n and \t, but when I reopen the page I see the same situation, so i don't know if it's a model problem or something else

Comment: So it works at first, but when you reload the page you have the error back ? You might have something in your code that sends you the string without the custom trim. But without more information I can't tell